# Item not added to the Wishlist if the user is not logged in Magento 2.3.4

Tags: wishlist, magento2.3.4, addtowishlist, account-dashboard, guest

Item is not adding to wishlist if user is not logged-in.

Scenario:

1. User is not logged-in
2. Click on Wishlist Button
3. Redirect to login page and showing error message to login.
4. After login customer redirect to My account Dashboard but product is not adding to wishlist.

How can I fixed the issue? I am using magento 2.3